# Plugin recommendation for directory site

Tags: user-registration, paypal

I am developing a site that will allow artists to sign up to a directory of artists to showcase their work etc. I can handle all the bespoke coding but I have one issue that I can't take care of and need a plugin recommendation for I think.

What I need is to create a process whereby a prospective artist can register for a normal WP user account but which will then only let them login when they have paid a recurring subscription via paypal. Once the payment has been authorised, I need the solution to grant them access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendations for plugins are 'out of scope' here. But you could do a search for 'paid subscriptions' in the WP plugin directory. Then you can contact the plugin's support area with your questions, and/or try them out on your site.

Comment: Not sure why there was a downvote (the answer is correct about 'out of scope', as seen by the 'hold' the question got), but glad to help with a generalized answer. If the answer is good for you, an 'answer accepted' is always appreciated by anyone.